# CryptographicException intermittently occurs when encrypting/decrypting with RSA

Tags: c#, security, encryption, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt data using RSA in C#.  I have the following MSTest unit test:

```
const string rawPassword = "mypass";

// Encrypt
string publicKey, privateKey;
string encryptedPassword = RSAUtils.Encrypt(rawPassword, out publicKey, out privateKey);
Assert.AreNotEqual(rawPassword, encryptedPassword,
    "Raw password and encrypted password should not be equal");

// Decrypt
string decryptedPassword = RSAUtils.Decrypt(encryptedPassword, privateKey);
Assert.AreEqual(rawPassword, decryptedPassword,
    "Did not get expected decrypted password");
```

It fails during decryption, but only sometimes.  It seems like whenever I set breakpoints and step through the test, it passes.  This made me think perhaps something wasn't finishing in time for decryption to occur successfully, and me slowing stepping through it while debugging gave it enough time to complete.  When it fails, the line it seems to fail at is `decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(bytesToDecrypt, false);` in the following method:

```
public static string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt, string privateKeyXml)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToDecrypt))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Cannot decrypt null or blank string"
        );
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(privateKeyXml))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid private key XML given");
    }
    byte[] bytesToDecrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes(textToDecrypt);
    byte[] decryptedBytes;
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);
        decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(bytesToDecrypt, false); // fail here
    }
    return ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedBytes);
}
```

It fails with this exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data

My `Encrypt` method is as follows:

```
public static string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt, out string publicKey,
    out string privateKey)
{
    byte[] bytesToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
    byte[] encryptedBytes;
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, false);
        publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
        privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
    }
    return ByteConverter.GetString(encryptedBytes);
}
```

The `ByteConverter` used throughout is just the following:

```
public static readonly UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
```

I've seen a few questions on StackOverflow about RSA encryption and decryption with .NET.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629992/c-rsa-encrypt-decrypt-throws-exception) was due to encrypting with the private key and trying to decrypt with the public key, but I don't think I'm doing that.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350516/how-do-i-decrypt-rsa-data-in-c-net-appropriately) has the same exception as me, but the selected answer was to use OpenSSL.NET, which I would prefer not to do.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you replace `ByteConverter.GetBytes` with `Convert.FromBase64String` and replace `ByteConverter.GetString` with `Convert.ToBase64String` and see if that helps.  `Bad Data` exception usually means that you have an invalid character in the data or that the length is not the correct length for decrypting.  I think using the Convert functions might fix your problems.

```
  public static readonly UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();

  public static string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt, out string publicKey,
    out string privateKey)
  {
     byte[] bytesToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
     byte[] encryptedBytes;
     using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
     {
        encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, false);
        publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
        privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
     }
     return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
  }

  public static string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt, string privateKeyXml)
  {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToDecrypt))
     {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Cannot decrypt null or blank string"
        );
     }
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(privateKeyXml))
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid private key XML given");
     }
     byte[] bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
     byte[] decryptedBytes;
     using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
     {
        rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);
        decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(bytesToDecrypt, false); // fail here
     }
     return ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedBytes);
  }
```

Comment: Hm, trying that gives me a different exception:  "System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array".  This occurred on the first line of `Encrypt`:  `byte[] bytesToEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(textToEncrypt);`.

Comment: @Sarah - Ok, I updated your example.  I tested it out and it looks liek it works.

Comment: That works!  Thanks.  I never would have thought to use that mix of `Convert`/`UnicodeEncoding`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with the conversion from bytes to string. Not all sequences of bytes are a valid UTF-16 encoding and you are using a UnicodeEncoding that silently ignores invalid bytes. If you used

```
public static readonly UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false, true);
```

instead, your code would have failed when trying to convert the bytes instead of silently replacing the invalid byte-pairs with [0xFFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

The fact that the test worked while debugging was a coincidence. You are using a random RSA key-pair, so sometimes you will get a encryption that is a valid UTF-16 encoding.

The fix is, as SwDevMan81 suggests, to use an encoding that can convert all possible byte-arrays. F.x. Base64-encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this class, sadly I don't remember the original author though..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Encryption
{

class AsymmetricED
{
    private static RSAParameters param = new RSAParameters();
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pp">Export private parameters?</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static RSAParameters GenerateKeys(bool pp)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        if (param.Equals(new RSAParameters()))
        {
            param = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
        }
        RSA.ImportParameters(param);
        return RSA.ExportParameters(pp);
    }
    static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            //Import the RSA Key information. This only needs
            //toinclude the public key information.
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

            //Encrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
            //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
            //later.  
            return RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return null;
        }

    }

    static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            //Import the RSA Key information. This needs
            //to include the private key information.
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

            //Decrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
            //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
            //later.  
            return RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            ConsoleColor col = Console.BackgroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.BackgroundColor = col;
            return null;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Use as:

```
Encryption.AsymmetricED.RSAEncrypt(Data, GenerateKeys(false), false);

Encryption.AsymmetricED.RSADecrypt(Data, GenerateKeys(true), false);
```

EDIT:
I also recommend that you don't use this for large data encryption.  Usually you would encrypt the actual data with a symmetric algorithm (AES, etc), then encrypt the symmetric key (randomly generated) with the RSA algorithm, then send the rsa encrypted symmetric key, and the symmetric key data..
You should also look at RSA signing, to make sure the data is coming from where it says it is..